# How to create a Source which is not affected by backpressure

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, backpressure

I want to test some Akka streams features like `conflate`. For this, I need to construct a source which is not affected by backpressure within a simple unit test. Naive attempts like

```
Source.tick(1.milli, 1.milli, "tick").map(_ => Random.nextDouble())
```

do not work because of backpressure. OTOH going over HTTP is probably overkill.

How would I create a **simple** `Source` for a unit test which is not affected by backpressure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Source.actorRef` which is - by design - not backpressure-enabled. See the example below:

```
  val actorRef: ActorRef = Source.actorRef(0, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
      .map(_ => Random.nextDouble())
      .to(yourSink).run()

  system.scheduler.schedule(1.milli, 1.milli, actorRef, "tick")(system.dispatcher)
```

The bufferSize parameter and the overflow strategy have been chosen randomly here, you'll need to adjust them to the needs of your test.

More info on `Source.actorRef` can be found in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.1/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#Source_actorRef).

Comment: Ah, very nice! Thank you, Stefano.